# Speed variable not being updated or not working after refresh

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to get the `speed` variable to change the speed of the ball, but when I set the `dx` and `dy` variables to the speed, they don't update after you lose a life. When I set `dx` and `dy` to the value of `Xspeed` and `Yspeed`, the speed doesn't change when you change difficulty.

I've tried setting the value of `dx` and `dy` to `Xspeed` and `Yspeed` because I thought it might keep the value instead of refreshing it, but it just doesn't change it when I want it to.

Full link to the code, https://codepen.io/Jacob-Bruce/pen/mQgbXa

```
// ball movement - change variables to change speed
var Xspeed = 2
var Yspeed = -2
var dx = Xspeed;
var dy = Yspeed;

function hardMode() {
   lives = 1;
   Xspeed = 7;
   Yspeed = -7;
   redraw();
}
```

I want the speed to be able to be changed with the difficulty buttons, and it to stay the same speed until you either die or change difficulty. Right now, it either changes speed once and doesn't at all.

Comment: If you got two variables that should contain the same value, why do you need two variables at all?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is binding the values of `dx` and `dy` to `Xspeed` and `Yspeed`, right? I don't quite understand why, but you should have a look here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense to have two variables, it was just my attempt at making something happen. But when I use the difficulty buttons to change the speed, when you lose a life, it reverts back to what it is set in the original declaration.